# React front end working but patch request to server is one render behind

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, async-await

I am trying to connect my react front end to a rest API I built containing a profile object. Not sure about the best practice to do this properly, would love some advice.

my user object in React contains an array of interests. From the front end, I am adding an individual interest to the array during an onSubmit, this is working fine.

Then I'm trying to make a patch request to my server and passing it the user.interests (array) to the interests array in my profile object. Not sure if this is because I am setting the front end first? or something to do with the asynchronous nature of JS but my server is always one render behind. The first patch req renders an empty array during my console.log and my second req only renders the first item, etc...

any advice on a possible solution?

```
const User = ({ user, dispatch }) => {
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState("");

  //FRONT END
  const handleNewInterest = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({
      type: ACTIONS.ADD_INTEREST,
      payload: {
        id: user.id,
        interest: interest
      }
    });
    setInterest("");
    editUser(user.interests);
  };

  //BACK END
  const editUser = async (value) => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/profiles/61038a313fb1c989fcabf571`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        interests: value
      })
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log("DATA", data));
  };
```

and here is my reducer

```
  const reducer = (users, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTIONS.ADD_USER:
        return [
          ...users,
          {
            id: action.payload.id,
            firstName: action.payload.firstName,
            lastName: action.payload.lastName,
            email: action.payload.email,
            interests: []
          }
        ];
      case ACTIONS.ADD_INTEREST:
        return users.map((user) => {
          if (user.id === action.payload.id) {
            return {
              ...user,
              interests: [...user.interests, action.payload.interest]
            };
          }
          return user;
        });
      case ACTIONS.DELETE_USER:
        return users.filter((user) => user.id !== action.payload.id);
      default:
        return users;
    }
  };

  const [users, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
```

Comment: Is `handleNewInterest` the submit handler you mention? What does the dispatched action do? Are you expecting it to update your global state and update the `user` prop instantly? What is handling that dispatched action?

Comment: @DrewReese yes it is my submit handler, I updated my post with the rest of my reducer functionality. It is updating my global users state upon submission